# CMake, custom command and dependencies

Tags: cmake

During my build process, a file generated by `add_custom_command` must the be compiled as C++. That's working but the generated file contains an include directive. When I modify the included file, the generated file is *not* recompiled.

There is an option `IMPLICIT_DEPENDS` for `add_custom_command`. But it does remake the generated file instead of just compiling it. And the documentation has a note

> Note that the IMPLICIT_DEPENDS option is currently supported only for Makefile generators and will be ignored by other generators.

What's the recommended way to be able to recompile the generated file without remaking it and without depending on a given generator?

---

An example:

```
% more foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

int const value = 36;

#endif
% more foo.in
#include "foo.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The answer is " << value << '\n';
    return 0;
}
% more CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Test)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT foo.cpp
  DEPENDS foo.in
  COMMAND cp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.in foo.cpp)

set_source_files_properties(foo.cpp PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
% mkdir build
% cd build
% cmake ..
...
% make
[ 33%] Generating foo.cpp
Scanning dependencies of target foo
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/foo.dir/foo.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable foo
[100%] Built target foo
% ./foo 
The answer is 36
% sed -i.bak -e 's/36/42/' ../foo.h
% make
[100%] Built target foo
% ./foo 
The answer is 36
```

I expect the second `make` to recompile `foo.cpp` (but **not** to regenerate it) so that the answer is 42.

Adding

```
  IMPLICIT_DEPENDS CXX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.in
```

to the `CMakeLists.txt` generates a correct executable but regenerates `foo.cpp` when not needed and it not available for other generators according to the documentation.

Comment: The things should work. Please, show (add to the question post) your **code**: probably, something wrong with it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev see the update..

Comment: Your example #worksforme. (w/o the IMPLICIT_DEPENDS.) `cmake version 3.20.3`

Comment: @nega which generators did you test with?

Comment: make and ninja.

Comment: @nega, I just tested and confirmed that it works with 3.20 (and that it doesn't with 3.19). Thanks.